# Binding does not work, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Binding in the collection Items works perfectly, but when I try to Binding the variable Count does not work, could anyone help me with this?

```
<Label Text="{Binding Count}" TextColor="#4F4F4F" FontSize="10" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
```

I did a test, moving the Label out of the ListView and it worked perfect, but I need it to work from within the Listview.

**ViewModel:**

```
 class ListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; }

            public ListViewModel()
            {
                Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>(new[]
                {
                    new Item { Text = "Test 1", Detail = "Detail 1", Foto = "computer2.png" },
                    new Item { Text = "Test 2", Detail = "Detail 2", Foto = "computer4.png" },

                });          


            private int count = 1;
            public int Count
            {
                get { return count; }
                set
                {
                    count = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
```

**XAML:**

```
 <ListView  
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 

            <ListView.Header>
                <StackLayout>

                  <Label Text="{Binding Count}"     
                  TextColor="#4F4F4F" FontSize="10" 
                  FontAttributes="Bold"/>  

                </StackLayout>
            </ListView.Header>

        </ListView>
```

Comment: Try adding `Header="{Binding .}"` to your `ListView`

Comment: Hi Gerald, I did the test but unfortunately it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like the following. Also i'm assuming what you've posted isn't your full code, as we can't see your implementation of OnPropertyChanged or how you are setting the count.

```
<ContentPage
//BlahBlah Headings
x:Name="PageName">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListView.Header>
            <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference PageName}, Path=BindingContext.Count}"     
              TextColor="#4F4F4F" FontSize="10" 
              FontAttributes="Bold"/>
        </StackLayout>
        </ListView.Header>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Hi App Pack, I did exactly as you asked, but it still did not work. :-(

The strange thing is that this way to work when using in Command with methods

Comment: without the full code and xaml it's difficult to see what's going on. There may be something odd going on here. change the reference in the binding  source to point at the root page (ContentPage or whatever is the root). eg give the content page a name and then change the x:reference to that name

Comment: Very good !!! Now it worked! Add in ContentPage a name as you requested and it worked perfect! Thank you!

Comment: updated answer based on comments in case someone else looks it up in future

Answer (score 0):

I have done this little repo and it works without particular bindings

ViewModel + Model

```
namespace TestRelativeLayout.ViewModels
{
    [ImplementPropertyChanged]
    public class MyPage4ViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
        public int Counter { get; set; } = 111;
        public string MyCounterFooter { get; set; } = "888";

        public MyPage4ViewModel() {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>(new[]
        {
                        new Item { Text = "Test 1", Detail = "Detail 1", Foto = "computer2.png" },
                        new Item { Text = "Test 2", Detail = "Detail 2", Foto = "computer4.png" },

                    });
        }

        public class Item
        {
            public string Detail { get; set; }
            public string Foto { get; set; }
            public string Text { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml

```
namespace TestRelativeLayout.ViewModels
{
    [ImplementPropertyChanged]
    public class MyPage4ViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
        public int Counter { get; set; } = 111;
        public string MyCounterFooter { get; set; } = "888";

        public MyPage4ViewModel() {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>(new[]
        {
                        new Item { Text = "Test 1", Detail = "Detail 1", Foto = "computer2.png" },
                        new Item { Text = "Test 2", Detail = "Detail 2", Foto = "computer4.png" },

                    });
        }

        public class Item
        {
            public string Detail { get; set; }
            public string Foto { get; set; }
            public string Text { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Result]